# Is it possible to send a constructor into ros node subscribe?

Tags: c++, boost, ros

I am trying to pass a class constructor into ros subscribe function.  Is it possible to have the constructor called when the topic is published to?

```
      class udpMsg
    {
        public:
        std::string udp;
        size_t posOfDelim;
        std::string token;
        udpMsg(){}; 
        udpMsg(const std_msgs::String::ConstPtr& msg)
        {
        udp = std::string(msg->data);
        posOfDelim = udp.find(delimiter);
        token = udp.substr(0, posOfDelim);
        }
}

    int main(int argc, char **argv)
    {



    ros::init(argc, argv, "listener");
    ros::NodeHandle n;
 A_pub = n.advertise<udpubsub::msgA>("Amsg", 1000);
 B_pub = n.advertise<udpubsub::msgB>("Bmsg", 1000);
udpMsg mainMsg;
ros::Subscriber sub = n.subscribe("chatter", 1000,mainMsg.udpMsg)
 ros::spin();
```

Comment: What are the types of the arguments to subscribe? I suspect it's looking for a callback function.  And I'm guessing it's not a member function but rather a free or static member function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you cannot pass a constructor as a function. `udpMsg` is the name of the class itself, not the name of a function.

You can write a separate "factory function" that creates objects, and pass *that* to `subscribe`, like

```
udpMsg create_message()
{ return udpMsg(); }
```